# RESTful services and MYSQL deployment in cloud

Tags: rest, azure, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, cloud

I have developed RESTful services with Asp.NET, Web API 2.0 and MySQL.

What are my options to deploy this in to the Cloud? I don't want a complete EC2 instance or Azure Virtual Machine.

Are there any cloud platform services where I can only get IIS server and a MYSQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below for good links on Azure and AWS options. Since you mention IIS, Azure may be your best bet. Keep in mind you should try and keep your API and DB in the same cloud data center to improve performance and reduce cost for ingress and egress.

**From an Azure perspective:**

[Take a look at their MySQL as a service offering (in preview)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mysql/?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-0_B3xRk2BVqm_.qNRR6CiQ&tduid=(1352266b17f0a2834f2bceed3b9d0b86)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-0_B3xRk2BVqm_.qNRR6CiQ)())

And then you can host your code in a couple of ways.

- [Asp.Net in an App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet)
- [An Azure Function](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/04/01/http-triggered-functions.aspx)

Using a combination of the above you can leverage PaaS and avoid having to manage your own VMs.

Further, look in to using a consumption plan to pay for only what you use.

**From an AWS perspective**

- [Use Amazon RDS (MySQL)](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/)
- [Use Lambda to host your API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html)

Again, here you wont need to manage servers either.

Comment: Thanks for reply, will check the links.

Comment: No worries. If you find what you are looking for, pop back and mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Do i have to separate Web API in to App Service and MYSQL to Azure Mysql. And then make connection between API and MYSQL. Is there anything like hosting (Webserver+Database)  together?

Comment: Yes, you have to keep them separate.